# C# windows forms DataTransferObject (DTO) Error

Tags: c#, visual-studio

i'm trying to figure out why my Domainclass can't inherit a UserDTO (**GebruikerDTO**) from the DTO, when creating a **GetDTO()** method.
I will show the code

The DTO class from which the Domainclass needs to inherit a UserDTO

**public ReviewDTO(string stuktekst, GebruikerDTO gebruiker)**:

```
namespace InterfaceLib
{
    public class ReviewDTO
    {
        public DateTime DatumTijd { get; }
        public GebruikerDTO Gebruiker { get; }
        public string StukTekst { get; }

        public ReviewDTO(string stuktekst, GebruikerDTO gebruiker)
        {
            this.StukTekst = stuktekst;
            this.Gebruiker = gebruiker;
            this.DatumTijd = DateTime.Now;
        }
```

The UserDTO (**"GebruikerDTO"**):

```
namespace InterfaceLib
{
    public class GebruikerDTO
    {
        public string Wachtwoord { get; }
        public string Gerbuikersnaam { get; }
        public string Alias { get; }
        public List<OutfitDTO> Outfits { get; } = new List<OutfitDTO>();
        public List<OnderdeelDTO> Onderdelen { get; } = new List<OnderdeelDTO>();

        public GebruikerDTO(string gerbuikersnaam, string wachtwoord, string alias)
        {
            this.Gerbuikersnaam = gerbuikersnaam;
            this.Wachtwoord = wachtwoord;
            this.Alias = alias;
        }
    }
```

The Domainclass which needs to inherit a UserDTO **("GebruikerDTO")**

**internal ReviewDTO GetDTO()**, Does not let me inherit **"(GebruikerDTO)gebruiker"**:

```
namespace BusnLogicLaag
{
    internal class Review
    {
        public DateTime DatumTijd { get; }
        public Gebruiker Gebruiker { get; }
        public string StukTekst { get; }

        public Review(string stuktekst, Gebruiker gebruiker)
        {
            StukTekst = stuktekst;
            Gebruiker = gebruiker;
            DatumTijd = DateTime.Now;
        }

        internal ReviewDTO GetDTO()
        {
            ReviewDTO dto = new ReviewDTO(StukTekst, (GebruikerDTO)gebruiker);
            return dto;
        }
```

The User (**"Gebruiker"**) Domain class:

```
namespace BusnLogicLaag
{
    public class Gebruiker
    {
        public string Wachtwoord { get; }
        public string Gerbuikersnaam { get; }
        public string Alias { get; }
        public List<Outfit> Outfits { get; } = new List<Outfit>();
        public List<Onderdeel> Onderdelen { get; } = new List<Onderdeel>();
        //Hier geen DTO's toch?

        public Gebruiker(string gerbuikersnaam, string wachtwoord, string alias)
        {
            Gerbuikersnaam = gerbuikersnaam;
            Wachtwoord = wachtwoord;
            Alias = alias;
        }
```

The error tells me:

*Cannot convert type BusnLogicLaag.Gebruiker to InterfaceLib.GebruikerDTO*

Both InterfaceLib and BusnLogicLaag are class libraries.

If anyone requires more info, please reply!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think you mean 'inherit' - you're just trying to access a variable that's not in scope. A property with the same reference *is* in scope though - change from `gebruiker` to `Gebruiker` (as you did with `StukTekst`).

Comment: Extrapolating from the code you've shared, I would expect you need `ReviewDTO dto = new ReviewDTO(StukTekst, Gebruiker.GetDTO());`

Comment: There's no inheritance in your classes. `(GebruikerDTO)gebruiker` is a *cast* operation that will always fail because `Gegruiker` doesn't inherit from `GebruikerDTO`. The suffix `DTO` means nothing, it's just how you named some types and methods. It doesn't introduce any relation between types

Comment: You didn't post the *problem* or any compilation error. The `Gebruiker` type is also missing, If it's the same as `Review` and `ReviewDTO` though, you'll get a compilation error

Comment: The question is not clear, can you post some more details.

Comment: Does the comment can help you?